# Solr query for terms closely and frequently used with another term

Tags: search, apache-solr

We are attempting to find terms (actually words) that most frequently appear in some proximity to a given term.

When using facetting like this:
`?q=myfield:tree&facet=on&facet.query=tree&facet.field=myfield` it appears we are getting the counts for the most-occuring words in `myfield`, next to `tree`.

**Question**: However, we would like to kind of *sub*-facette the query, including the *distances* for each term (or an average distance).

The `myfield`-field is stored, tokenized, the termvectors are stored and offset and position are stored with the termvector.